# how to remove row from class base table using jquery

Tags: jquery

My html table having class hour-logging

and td having id like text1 , text2 etc

i want to remove text1 row from all table which contain class name hour-logging.

How can i do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if `text` is the id of a td then you cannot have duplicate entries for them

Comment: can you share your html sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

$('table.hour-logging tr#text1').remove();

it will work

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for something like this:

```
$("table.hour-logging td#text1").closest("tr").remove();
```

The selector will find the table cell (`<td>`) contained within a table element with the `hour-logging` class. It will then use the `closest` function to extract the table row (`<tr>`) of the selected cell, and them remove it with `remove()`.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of giving you the answer I will give you the bricks :

- http://api.jquery.com/remove/
- http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

OK since you need a "real" answer  here I go.

To remove every row inside a table with class `hour-logging` and ID starting with `text`

`$(table.hour-logging td[id^=text]').closest('tr').remove();`

And to just remove an element with a specific ID (assuming it's unique) :

`$('#text1').closest('tr').remove();`

You can add more restriction to this selection by using the full selector :

`$(table.hour-logging td#text1').closest('tr').remove();`

Comment: Agreed, voting to delete.

Comment: Also [this is relevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13369/is-it-okay-to-answer-a-stack-overflow-question-with-a-link?lq=1)

Comment: @Lix well, last time I fully answer such a trivial question people told the OP to first look out himself for the answer. Obviously he hasn't done any research first.

Comment: @Lix what i think even if this is not an answer it is related to answer only

Comment: @Lix http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Comment: @tec - Did you read that blog post? `"We discourage “answers” that are links..."` Before your edit, your answer contained ONLY links. You even explicitly said: `"Instead of giving you the answer..."`.

Comment: You've now edited your post to look much more like an answer - so I guess you agree with me on some level.

Comment: @Lix I never said I've made a full answer the first time. I said I wanted the OP to lookout himself for the answer but obviously I was wrong. I personally don't like spoonfeeding but if it's the way of doing things around here okay...

Comment: The point is that you posted an answer that didn't really answer the question. All you did was provide a link to where the answer actually is. Those three links **are** helpful - and could have made a great comment - but on their own - they don't constitute an answer.

Comment: I also agree with you that spoonfeeding is bad - that's why I never give code only answers - I'll always include an explanation and if possible some links for reference.